# Как реализовать вывод одного и того же рандомного числа при помощи SingleTon?

Tags: php

Ожидается вывод одного и того же рандомного числа 4 раза. А в результате только один раз.Вот код:

```
class Single{
    private static $instance = null;
    public $result;
    private function __construct(){
        $this->result  = random_int(100, 999);
        $this->getresult();
        }
    protected function getresult(){
        echo "Result:" . $this->result;
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        return static::$instance ?: static::$instance = new static();
    }
}
Single::getInstance();
Single::getInstance();
Single::getInstance();
Single::getInstance();
```

Comment: Ну да, смысл Синглтона в том, что он создаётся один раз. Т.е.конструктор отрабатывает один раз. А ты в конструкторе вызываешь другой метод. Это неверно

Comment: Получи инстанс и только вот у него вызывай метод. Вот и всё

Answer (score -1):

```
class Single{
    private static $instance = null;
    public $result;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->result  = random_int(100, 999);
        $this->getresult();
        }
    protected function getresult(){
        echo "Result:" . $this->result;
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        return static::$instance ?? static::$instance = new static();
        // return static::$instance ?: static::$instance = new static();
    }
}
new Single();

new Single();

new Single();
new Single();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]